# Is it possible to object-select a heredoc or "here document" with vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, heredoc

One of Vim's great strengths is [object-select](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#object-select), offering quick manipulation of content inside words, paragraphs and assorted delimiters.

For example,

```
vi{
```

will select everything inside a pair of {} braces.

Is there any equivalent functionality for selecting a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) or heredoc:

```
<<<HTML
    ....
    ....
HTML;
```

---

Based on 
ErichBSchulz's answer I came up with the following for an heredoc inner select:

```
nmap <F6> ?<<<<CR>w*kV?<<<<CR>j

?<<<<CR>w    " find beginning tag (after <<<)
*k           " find matching end tag and go up 1 line
V            " enter visual mode
?<<<<CR>j    " find beginning tag and go down 1 line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking about the earlier posts and trying to take them a step closer. This wont be 100% reliable (ie will break if the starting tag occurs within the heredoc but something like:

```
?<<< "find begining
w    " go to starting tag
*    " find starting tag
v    " enter visual mode (could use Upper V to do an 'ambientish' object select 
n    " find end tag
e    " optional include end tag
```

Edit: Ken has improved the sequence as above, so I suggest you use his better key mapping for an 'inner' heredoc select:

```
nmap <F6> ?<<<<CR>w*kV?<<<<CR>j
```

(this is based on php style heredocs)

Comment: Thank you! I'd actually forgotten about this question but you put me onto the right path

Comment: Thanks Ken, nice tweak, but there's a typo in your key map - should be upper V - ie: nmap <F6> ?<<<<CR>w*kV?<<<<CR>j

Answer (score 4):

For selecting heredoc's I usually place the cursor at the first line, over the *heredoc identifier* and press <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>*</kbd>

<kbd>V</kbd> will start a line selection, and <kbd>*</kbd> will start a search, going to the next match of the identifier, the end of the heredoc...

Answer (score 2):

A `<<''` heredoc terminated by an empty line is easy, if you're already at the start (`?<<^M^M`): `v}` selects from here until the empty line.

Otherwise, in your example the best I can think of is `v/^HTML`.

Answer (score 2):

There's this plugin that let's you define your own text objects.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2100

I imagine it would be nice to define one so you could say 'yih' (yank in heredoc) so you don't have to explicitly go to the start.

Note I haven't fooled around with this myself.

If you just want a visual select you could.

```
 nnoremap <leader>ih ?HTML<cr>V/HTML<cr>
```